# Resource reference with name 'jdbc/devl' not found in ibm-web-bnd.xml

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere, web.xml, ibm-rad

RAD 7, WebSphere 7.

ibm-web-bnd.xml:

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/devl" binding-name="jdbc/devl" />
```

web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/devl</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
  <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
  <mapped-name>jdbc/devl</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
```

This conforms to the examples I see on the internet.  This comes up because I am converting this app to servlet 2.5.  As I understand it, the res-ref-name in web.xml should match the name attribute in resource-ref.  The binding-name then matches the datasource defined in the admin console.  To make it simple, I made them all match.

Is there another setting somewhere?  Because this produces the error described in the title of the question.

Comment: Yes, the `<resource-ref name="...">` should match the `<res-ref-name>` (and the `binding-name="..."` should match the data source name, but that would be a different error).  I'm not sure what's wrong. Can you update your question with the full error message? Perhaps there is a hint in the error message.

Comment: @bkail - Actually, that IS the full message.  It's an XML validation error.  If I run with errors I get a regular jndi "what the heck is this" type exception.  Like so:  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "comp/env/devl" not found in context "java:".

Comment: @bkail - I am able to make the XML validation error go away, but the jndi exception remains.  I found some config files related to the project facet that thought the project was still in servlet 2.2.  I thought just changing the web.xml and the .xmi's into xmls accomplished this.  Are there other settings I am missing?

Comment: If you can include the full error message (with timestamp, component, message ID, etc.) or exception (with full stack trace, all caused by, etc.), then I can try to take a closer look. I'm familiar with the product internals, so sometimes I can give a better answer (or ask more direct questions) if I can see all the information.

Comment: Please attach full exception and also piece of code that does the lookup. As from the fragment of exception `NameNotFoundException: Name "comp/env/devl"` , the reference name is `dev1` not `jdbc/dev1` if you pasted it correctly...

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue many times. It disappeared when I closed the eclipse and when I reopened it I made a "project -> clean". I hope it works for the next person who has this error.
[image]

Also make sure you have the web.xml header updated to 2.5 or higher (3.0).This is related to the facets of the project, make sure they are with the same version
[image]

if it doesn't let you change it, you should change it in this file : "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml"

If the error continues, you should generate the binding file again. Make sure you have the correct server settings in the facets of the project
[image]

To generate the file you must do it from java EE Tools.
[image]

Remember that ibm-web-bnd.xml and web.xml must be in the same directory

Build, and clean project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, try to update the web module version in project.facet.core.xml. It should be in synch with the web.xml web-app version.

Comment: Also, it can happen if you have the correct web module version in the facet (sigh). I fixed *uninstalling* the `Dynamic Web Module` facet and reinstalling it again with the same version (2.5 in my case)